# In the text, words of a given length are replaced by a specified substring of arbitrary length

Tags: java, string

I need to replace all words given length by random substring of arbitraty lenght.For example, the length given word is 3, thus i need to replace "the" to "a"

```
String str = "Java is the best language in the world!";
String randomWord = "a"; 
//Manipulations
System.out.println(str);
// Outputs: Java is a best language in a world!
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Look at the [Javadoc for String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), skim the page until you find something that lets you replace something. Use that in your code. Be aware that Strings are immutable, so you cannot modify the original String but you'll get back a new changed string. Good luck! See also [ask].

Comment: `str.replaceAll("\\s[A-Za-z]{3}\\s", " a ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An algorithm like this should work:

```java
String str = "Java is the best language in the world!";
String randomWord = "a";
int givenLength = 3;

// Split the string into an array containing each word:
String arr[] = str.split(" ");

// Loop through and find & replace all words of the given length
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i].length() == givenLength) {
        arr[i] = randomWord;
    }
}

// Rejoin words into a new string
String output = String.join(" ",arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Java is the best language in the world!";
        int wordLength = 3;
        String replaceWord = "a";
        Function<String, String> replaceFunction = element -> {
            if (element.toCharArray().length == wordLength) {
                return replaceWord;
            } else {
                return element;
            }
        };
        String result = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                .toList()
                .stream()
                .map(replaceFunction)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: It seems unnecessary to call toCharArray(). You can get the String length with `element.length()`.